# Fade Out Multiple Dynamically-Created Elements with an on.click of One of Them

Tags: jquery, dom, dynamic, onclick

I have a save link and a cancel link that are both generated dynamically. I know how to do `$('body').on('click', 'a#cancel-unique_id', function(){`

But I need to be able to also manipulate the save link with the on click of the cancel. But I get "save" is not defined, because it's dynamic.

```
$('body').on('click', 'a[id^="cancel-"]', function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    $id = this.id;
    var sfx = $id.replace('cancel-', '');
    var save = $('a#save-'+sfx);
    var cancel = $(this);
    cancel.fadeOut(500);
    save.fadeOut(500);      
}
```

They actually both fade out but I still get the javascript error saying that "save" is not defined.
Both save and cancel are elements created in a separate on click function.

So how can I access the dynamically-created "save" element from within the dynamically-created "cancel" element's on.click function?

Comment: Is `sfx` an empty string from `var sfx = $id.replace('cancel-', '');` producing selector `a#save-` at `$('a#save-'+sfx);` ? Or , does `$id` contain additional string parts ? If possible, can post string of `$id` ? Thanks

Comment: sfx is not an empty string. It's a randomly generated number that comes after cancel- or save- or whatever. They all match in their respective table rows. Example: `a#save-209122`

Comment: What tasks to perform at `#save-` ? If `#save-` does `fadeOut` , tried to utilize `fadeOut` callback ? i.e.g., `save.fadeOut(500, function() {//do stuff with "$(this)" / "#save-[randID]" });` ?

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. I think I have it all working now as desired.

Comment: See complete at http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut . Thanks